# Visual Studio Code: failed to load project file (works in VS2017)

Tags: visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I´m trying to use Visual Studio Code, so I installed the current version (1.25.0). I open the project folder and VSC starts doing stuff with OmniSharp, producing the following error:

[image]

(Sorry, error is in german, saying that the file or assembly could not be found and that it can´t load the project file .csproj)

So, I checked the folder: the file is there and visual studio 2017 loads and builds the project as expected.

I´m new to VSC, so please tell me if I need to provide more information from some VSC logs or something.

I´d like to be able to open the project and work with VSC, so thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I am assuming you have installed this? [C # Extenstion for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp) and you are trying to open a dotnet core application and not a full framework project?

Comment: No, it´s not core, but yes, I installed that extension. I´m trying to open the whole solution (containing several projects), as I did in visual studio 2017.

Comment: Unfortunately VSCode is not designed to be used with the full framework but only for the cross-platform dotnet core development. [Source](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp)

Comment: Ah, okay, I didn´t know that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

From the comment
`I am assuming you have installed this? C # Extenstion for VSCode and you are trying to open a dotnet core application and not a full framework project?`

The best way to go about is `uninstall C# extension` and you will be fine to open the code in vs code again.